# sklearn missing from dist-packages

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda

I needed to use the latest version of the sklearn which includes MLP. I had installed sklearn through pip but it didn't go for latest version. so I downloaded the dev version trying to build/install it manually, but it didn't work and still, MLP is missing from the neural network. I decided to remove sklearn, but it was only possible by using conda ( as they have mentioned in their website) and as am stupid, I removed the sklearn folder from dist-packages ( i couldn't use conda). now there is no sklearn folder there, but python is still able to import it( i don't know from where) and I can't install the dev version.
I need first, remove sklearn totally from the system, then install the dev version somehow. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, type in your command prompt / terminal in Linux or Mac

```
pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
```